# Case Article vs. Knowledgebase Case Article. What's the difference?

Tags: reporting, knowledge, custom-report-type, articles

I am working with reporting on Knowledge Articles.  One metric the business would like to see is cases being associated with articles.  This is pretty straight forward and I use the [CaseArticle](http://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_casearticle.htm) Object.

In setting up custom report type, I also see this KnowledgeBase Case Article (see below).  I can't seem to find much on it, or the use case for it.

What is it and should I be using this for some of my metrics?  What is the difference between Case Article and KnowledgeBase Case Article, and when should each be used?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have that object "Knowledgebase Case Articles", it looks like is a custom object you have in the org, I checked in 2 of my orgs with Knowledge and none of them have it. The "Case Article" object does not appear as an option to create a custom report type.

To report on Cases with articles attached, just used the report called "Cases With Articles" from this package. https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003HXO9EAO

Comment: Wow, do I feel stupid.  You are absolutely correct.  I spent all my time looking for documentation on it, never thought to check that it wasn't standard.  Something someone built years ago for a bunch of different object.  No wonder I couldn't find documentation on it.  Thanks